# NSTableView filling with multiple entity's

Tags: macos, core-data

I'm working with Core Data and displaying the data in a NSTableView.
From one Entity showing the data works fine and i'm abble to add data.
Bud what i want is to display records from multiple entity's in one NSTableView.
At this time i can't find any way to do this.

What i want is:
Entity: Customer.
With Attribute's: firstName, surName ....

Entity: Invoice.
With Attribute: invoiceDate, orderDate .....

I've created an relation between the entity's.

How can i show 1 row with the name of the customer and the invoiceData.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: So an entity and its to-one relationship both in the same cell? What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: What i got is the following.
4 Entity’s:

1. Event.
Attribute:
eventDescription.
eventDate.
eventPlace.

2. Customer.
Attribute:
firstName.
middleName.
surName.
emailAddress.

3. Invoice.
Attribute:
invoiceDate.
orderDate.
invoiceNumber.

4. Article.
Attribute:
articleDescription.
articlePrice.
articleQuantity.

Comment: The relation’s:
Event << -- >> Customer.
Customer < -- >> Invoice.
Invoice < -- >> Article.

What i want:
A NSTableView with multiple collumns.
Column 1 = eventDescription.
Column 2 = firstName.
Column 3 = surName.
Column 4 = invoiceNumber

You see that the tableview is filled with data from several entity’s.

Hope you understand what i want to create.

Comment: please edit the question, that info in comments is unreadable

Comment: Later this evening i will try to repost the question.

Comment: Posted it allready.

Comment: edit the question, don't add an answer, there should be an edit button by your question :)

Comment: I try, bud every time the text is getting pushed together.

Comment: Let's start simple.  
I have 2 entity's. Customer and Invoice.  
There is a relation from one customer to many Invoices.  
They have diverend attributes. I have one NSTableView. With multiple columns. A column for the firstname, one for the middlename, one for the surName and one for the invoicenumber. Firstname, middleName and surName are attributes of the Customer entity. Invoicenumber is a attribute of the Invoice entity. How can i make this happen. It's all conenected from a NSArrayController.

Comment: No mather what i try all the text get's put together and the new lines are gone.

Please read my new question below.

Comment: You can bind to key paths, for example `customer.firstName`.

Comment: That doesn't work.  Error i get: 2016-07-24 16:37:51.861 AdminMustBe[14813:8546591] [<Customer 0x6080000c4a60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Customer is not key value coding-compliant for the key "invoiceOrderDate".  <br/> The tableview get's it data from an NSArrayController.

Comment: The key paths must be relative to the entity of the array controller. If the entity is `Article`, the key path is `invoice.OrderDate`. You can't display invoice data in a list of customers this way, which invoice should be used?

Comment: I put in an new question below for adding an image. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: After a lot of trying i got it to work.
I had to subclass the NSManagedObject.

Now it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I got is the following 4 entities:

1. **Event**

Attributes:

```
eventDescription.
eventDate.
eventPlace.
```

2. **Customer**

Attributes:

```
firstName.
middleName.
surName.
emailAddress.
```

3. **Invoice**

Attributes:

```
invoiceDate.
orderDate.
invoiceNumber.
```

4. **Article**

Attributes:

```
articleDescription.
articlePrice.
articleQuantity.
```

The relations:

```
Event << -- >> Customer.
Customer < -- >> Invoice.
Invoice < -- >> Article.
```

What I want: A NSTableView with multiple columns.

- Column 1 - eventDescription.
- Column 2 - firstName.
- Column 3 - surName.
- Column 4 - invoiceNumber

You see that the tableview is filled with data from several entities.

Hope you understand what I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

I have several event's where i take photo's.
I put that event in my administration.
A customers orders photo's from an event.
So i create an invoice where the customer is related to the event.
The invoice is put in the NSSet relation by the customer.
Later i put articles in the invoice.

I want to show in the NSTableView the rows containing:
Column 1: eventName.
Column 2: customerName.
Column 3: invoiceOrderDate.
Column 4: invoiceDate
Column 5: invoiceNumber.

Below i have a picture of my Coare Data Model.

Hope you understand what i want.

[Care Data Model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyUbS.png)